# Word add textbox in Ribbon(xml file) in office add in. using office.js

Tags: office365, office-js, office365api, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm working on an Word 365 Add-in. I have a working Manifest XML that shows an icon with the icon responding to a function click. How would I go about adding a textbox to ribbon for add value.

Answer (score 1):

The Office JS APIs for extending the Ribbon or context menus support only buttons and drop-down menus for buttons. Quote from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands)

> A Control element can be either a Button or a Menu. Use Menu to
>   specify a drop-down list of button controls. Currently, only buttons
>   and menus are supported.

For getting input, define a **taskpane** with the controls required. It's possible to have the [task pane displayed automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document) when the add-in is loaded.